# Reassign TableView Cell Variable from another ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, tableview

I'm working on an App where you can track your reading Progress for Books. I have 3 ViewControllers. One is the HomeViewController, where I have a TableView which displays the book. Second is the AddBookController, where you can enter some data, press a Button and create a new row in the TableView. Third is the BookDetailViewController, which is showing when you click on the selected row. Here I am stuck. There is a button you press and the corresponding TableView Cell should update its page number.

Can I use Notification Center for this? There is no Segue from HomeViewController to BookDetailViewController.

**HomeViewController**

```
class HomeViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, SendingBookDataProtocol {

    @IBOutlet weak var addBookButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
    
    var items = [BookItem]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView?.delegate = self
        tableView?.dataSource = self

        let nib = UINib(nibName: "BookCell", bundle: nil)
        tableView?.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "BookCell")
    }

    func sendDataToHomeController(bookEntry item:BookItem) {
        items.append(item)
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        items.count
    }
    
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
      let bookDetailVc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "BookDetailView") as? BookDetailViewController

        let item = items[indexPath.row]
          
        let currentPageInt = Float(item.currentPage)!
        let totalPagesInt = Float(item.totalPages)!
          
          
        bookDetailVc?.lblName = item.title
        bookDetailVc?.lblCurrentPage = item.currentPage
        bookDetailVc?.lblTotalPages = item.totalPages
    
          self.navigationController?.pushViewController(bookDetailVc!, animated: true)
                                     
  }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "BookCell", for: indexPath) as! BookCell
        let item = items[indexPath.row]
        
        cell.bookImage.image = item.image
        cell.title.text = item.title
        cell.author.text = item.author
        cell.pageNumbers.text = "P. " + item.currentPage + " / " + item.totalPages
        
        cell.title.text = item.title

        return cell
    }

        override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
            if segue.identifier == "getBookData" {
                let addBookVC: AddBookController = segue.destination as! AddBookController
                addBookVC.delegate = self
            }
        }
}
```

**BookDetailView**

```
class BookDetailViewController: HomeViewController{

    @IBOutlet weak var bookTitle: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var currentPageDetail: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var totalPagesDetail: UILabel!

    var lblName = String()
    var lblCurrentPage = String()
    var lblTotalPages = String()


 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        bookTitle.text = lblName
        currentPageDetail.text = lblCurrentPage
        totalPagesDetail.text = lblTotalPages

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

your `self.navigationController?` is null?

try it
`self.present(bookDetailVc!, animated: true)`

I hope this helps you.